# Cannot submit Checkbox through nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, form-for

Im trying to create an application were teachers a able to select students each day who aren't in school. I created the models through nifty-generators gem. The problem is that it wont submit to the notpresents table. Please help.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: students
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  group_id   :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :group_id
  belongs_to :days
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: notpresents
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  student_id :integer
#  day_id     :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Notpresent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_id, :day_id
  belongs_to :days
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: days
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :presents 
  has_many :notpresents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notpresents
end
```

And view _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @day do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

<% for student in Student.find(:all) %>
        <div>
            <%= check_box_tag :notpresents, student.id%>
            <%= student.name %>
        </div>

    <% end %>


  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to work with nested attributes there. Please go through this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and follow.

Comment: Might I suggest renaming Notpresent to Absence?

Comment: @SyedAslam I've tried the neste railscast *revised* with no luck. I can get the correct params it just wont pass it to the correct table.

Comment: @ilikepie Yeah! Its just last-hour-of-work-week-brain at work… :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the nifty-generators gem, but if a student can be absent in many days, and a day can have many students absent, shouldn't you have a many-to-many relationship?

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :days, through: :notpresents
  has_many :notpresent
end

class Days < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date
  has_many :students, through: :notpresents
  has_many :notpresent
end

class :Notpresents < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_id, :day_id
  belongs_to :students
  belongs_to :days
end
```

It could also be a **[has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association)** association, but with a **[has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)** you could have a string or text attribute to make a note about the absence or something like that.

I recommend using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for the form, it makes it so easy:

app/controllers/days_controller.rb:

```
def edit
  @day = Day.find(params[:id])
end
```

app/views/days/_form.html.erb :

```
<%= simple_form_for @day do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :students, as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I ended up with this solution. the only truble I have is the styling and wrapping of the inputs and label that simple_form is generating for associations.